# Creating an AVPlayer for video

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am creating an AVPlayer to display a video. I have some code to create the Player but nothing displays. I'm not sure if the URL is not working or if the player it's self is not working.

Here is the code I am using to create the player:

```
self.playing = NO;

AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
player = [player initWithURL:self.videoURL];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[[[self view] layer] insertSublayer:playerLayer atIndex:3];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[player play];
```

Here is the code to save the video:

```
self.videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSLog(@"%@", self.videoURL);

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.videoURL = self.videoURL;
```

Comment: Why are you inserting the layer instead of adding it? (`[[self.view layer] addSublayer:playerLayer]`;)

Comment: check this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253373/cant-play-avplayer-local-video-from?rq=1